# Why does SUM(...) on an empty recordset return NULL instead of 0?

Tags: sql-server, null

*I understand* why `null + 1` or (`1 + null`) returns `null`: `null` means "unknown value", and if a value is unknown, its successor is unknown as well. The same is true for most other operations involving null.[*]

However, I *don't understand* why the following happens:

```
SELECT SUM(someNotNullableIntegerField) FROM someTable WHERE 1=0
```

This query returns `null`. Why? There are no unknown values involved here! The WHERE clause returns *zero* records, and the sum of an empty set of values is `0`.[**] Note that the set is not *unknown*, it is *known to be empty*.

I know that I can work around this behaviour by using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`, but I'm trying to understand *why* this behaviour, which appears counter-intuitive to me, was chosen.

Any insights as to why this makes sense?

---

[*] with some notable exceptions such as `null OR true`, where obviously `true` is the right result since the unknown value simply does not matter.

[**] just like the product of an empty set of values is `1`. Mathematically speaking, if I were to extend $(Z, +)$ to $(Z union {null}, +)$, the obvious choice for the identity element would still be `0`, not `null`, since `x + 0 = x` but `x + null = null`.

Comment: Perhaps because you are using an aggregate.

Comment: When you add nothing you do not get 0, you get nothing.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: I believe NULL is the lack of a value rather than an "unknown" value

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: If you add, you have to start at something (`add` is an operation defined on *two* operands). If you start at `0`, it all works out: `0 + valueOfRecord1 + valueOfRecord2 = the sum of record1 and record2`. If you start at `null`, it won't work: `null + valueOfRecord1 + valueOfRecord2 = null`.

Comment: Yes but if you do not start at all (*as in your case*) you get nothing ;)

Comment: @Heinzi "you have to start at something" - do you mean in math, or in SQL? If the latter, citation needed.

Comment: @LarsH: In math. I'm just curious *why* SQL chose a model for addition that's different than the one used in math.

Comment: @Heinzi: In math, as you say, addition is an operation (function) defined on *at least two* operands. Therefore, the `add()` function with zero arguments does not return zero (if it did, the function would also be defined on zero arguments). Rather, `add()` with no arguments is undefined. `add()` *could be* defined for 0 or 1 argument if that's convenient for the purpose at hand. So I would say, the decision whether to define `add()` with no arguments is fairly arbitrary in math and in computer languages. But I agree that the most general definition would start with zero.

Comment: Consider the inverse: If one _did want_ `null` for values that contained null, how would you manage it? Changing `null`s to `0` for the purposes of aggregation is easy, as you point out in your question, but the other way may not be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ANSI-SQL-Standard defines the result of the SUM of an empty set as NULL. Why they did this, I cannot tell, but at least the behavior should be consistent across all database engines.

Reference: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt on page 126:

> b) If AVG, MAX, MIN, or SUM is specified, then
>
> ```
>          Case:
>
>          i) If TXA is empty, then the result is the null value.
> ```

TXA is the operative resultset from the selected column.

Comment: I think this is for consistency, since the only sensible value for `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, so then I guess they decided not to make `SUM` a special case. The only special case is `COUNT`. Shame the standard doesn't include the rational behind it.

Comment: I've started [a question on dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25435/5273) about *why* it was standarized in this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you mean empty table you mean a table with only `NULL` values, That's why we will get `NULL` as output for aggregate functions. You can consider this as by design for SQL Server.

**Example 1**

```
CREATE TABLE testSUMNulls
(
    ID TINYINT
)
GO

INSERT INTO testSUMNulls (ID) VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)

SELECT SUM(ID) FROM testSUMNulls
```

**Example 2**

```
CREATE TABLE testSumEmptyTable
(
    ID TINYINT
)
GO

SELECT SUM(ID) Sums FROM testSumEmptyTable
```

In both the examples you will `NULL` as output..

Comment: `When you mean empty table you mean a table with only NULL values,` ... nope, definitely not.